# Kdenlive: GUI Issues

Tags: 16.04, kdenlive

I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I am having issues. I am trying to apply a dark theme to Kdenlive, and it's not working. Using the Qt5 Settings tool makes some things dark and some things not dark, and it looks messy. Can anyone get me going in the right direction to correctly apply a dark theme to Kdenlive? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you use kdenlive from default ubuntu, or from PPA

The best is that you use the PPA of themselves:

[image]

https://kdenlive.org/download/

Answer (score -1):

The solution found in [this thread](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=265&t=130860) on the KDE forums worked for me:

```
sudo apt install plasma-workspace
sudo apt install plasma-desktop
```

Try running the two above commands in a terminal to full re-install the Plasma dependency tree.